# Pull value for HostName for IPconfig command

Tags: regex

I have a text file for IPCONFIG command, and am interested to obtain value for HOST NAME i.e. S4333AAB45 utilizing REGEX.

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : S4333AAB45
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
```

I tried following option and it didn't work

```
/\bHost Name\s+(\d+)/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would use:

```
/\s+Host Name.*: (\w+)$/
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use Field Splitting with AWK

You don't say what regular expression engine you're using, or why you need to use a regular expression to match the host name portion. If you have access to AWK, you can treat this as a field-splitting issue instead. For example:

```
awk '/\<Host Name\>/ { print $NF }' /tmp/foo
```

### Use Known Line Positions

Assuming you've got Cygwin or similar installed, you can use the position of the interesting record to get the data you want without a regular expression at all. For example:

```
cat /tmp/foo | head -n3 | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' '
```

Just replace the *cat* command with your call to *ipconfig* instead, and you should get the results you want.

### Use sed Instead

You can also use sed to find the line you're interested in, and print out just the trailing word on the line. For example:

```
sed -n '/\<Host Name\>/ s/.*[[:space:]]\([[:alnum:]]\+\)$/\1/p' /tmp/foo
```

Comment: I could use REGEX for Java or Perl for Network Mgt tool.  Need only single line REGEX to accomplish the job of pulling out S4333AAB45.  This is the Host Name as shown in the example earlier. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your host had a letter "S" as the first character of the host name, so "(\d+)" wouldn't be correct for matching your host name.  You also failed to account for the dots and colon on the host name line.  So the answer from weexpectedTHIS should do the trick.  But for your information, here's how you could get the host name without first creating an intermediate file.

`` $ipconfig = `ipconfig /all`; ``

`($host) = $ipconfig =~ /^\s*Host Name.*:\s*(\w+)/m;`

You would need the "/m" in there so that the "^" will match the start of any line in the multi-line contents of $ipconfig.  I tend to use "\s*" instead of "\s+" as a sort of insurance against future changes in the output format (where white space is often removed or expanded in newer versions of a command).